# Symfony3.4 Form errors rendered twice

Tags: symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I have a form with **author** and **message** fields and **NotBlank()** validation on both.

In twig, I do this:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}

    {{ form_errors(form.author) }}
    {{ form_label(form.author) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.author) }}


    {{ form_errors(form.message) }}
    {{ form_label(form.message) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.message) }}

{{ form_end(form) }}
```

If I press **Save** button with empty fields ***I EXPECT*** to see this:

[image]

***But I get this:***

[image]

Somehow the bottom error message comes from the **{{ form_label(...) }}** I say this, because if I comment the labels out and use static HTML for labels, the output is like on first picture.

I would prefer not to use static HTML for labels, but I don't understand where the second error messages came from.

Below my code:

**Form**

```
class TestFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('author', TextType::class, ['required' => false, 'constraints' => [new NotBlank()]])
            ->add('message', TextType::class, ['required' => false, 'constraints' => [new NotBlank()]])
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class)
        ;
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
class TestController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/testing", name="test")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(TestFormType::class);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid())
        {
            return $this->redirectToRoute('test');
        }

        return $this->render('test/index.html.twig', [
            'form' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Template**
    {% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
    {% block title %}Hello TestController!{% endblock %}

```
{% block body %}

    <p>This is a test...</p>

    {{ form_start(form) }}

        {{ form_errors(form.author) }}
        {{ form_label(form.author) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.author) }}

        {{ form_errors(form.message) }}
        {{ form_label(form.message) }}
        {{ form_widget(form.message) }}

    {{ form_end(form) }}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Maybe, you could use form_row instead, no ?

Comment: @Adrien yes, but I anyway wanted to know why this happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For bootstrap theme error block is [integrated in label](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig#L229-L233). 
So you need either to remove `form_errors` block in your template or to override `form_label` block.
You can use `form_row` (as @Adrien suggests in commentaries) as there is no `form_errors` [call](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_4_layout.html.twig#L277-L290)

Comment: Thanks for the references. This was exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You've explicitly added form_errors whereas error message already rendered via form_label. either you can remove form_errors or form_label.

Comment: stackoverflow.com/q/56338792/8631622 Please look into this problem. I did everything I could. But I could not solve this problem @Mitesh Vasava